# Postgres sorting entirely from memory seems to be CPU bound?

Tags: database, postgresql, caching, memory

In sort operations the main bottleneck is the disk I/O, i.e fetching all of the data from disk.

So I thought of experimenting it with [IMCS](https://github.com/knizhnik/imcs) and in-memory columnar plugin for Postgres.

Below is the regular query plan.(I didn't include an index for learning purposes)

```
perf_test=# explain (analyze,buffers) select * from users_act_demo order by userid limit 10;
                                                                QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Limit  (cost=410011.04..410011.06 rows=10 width=14) (actual time=4328.393..4328.396 rows=10 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=3 read=59875
   ->  Sort  (cost=410011.04..437703.22 rows=11076875 width=14) (actual time=4328.387..4328.389 rows=10 loops=1)
         Sort Key: userid
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
         Buffers: shared hit=3 read=59875
         ->  Seq Scan on users_act_demo  (cost=0.00..170643.75 rows=11076875 width=14) (actual time=0.042..1938.043 rows=11076719 loops=1)
               Buffers: shared read=59875
Planning time: 42.055 ms
Execution time: 4328.482 ms
(10 rows)
```

After doing `cs_load` which is a function that moves all of the pages into memory.After that, below is the query plan.

```
perf_test=# explain (analyze,buffers) select * from users_act_demo order by userid limit 10;
                                                                QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Limit  (cost=410011.04..410011.06 rows=10 width=14) (actual time=3902.765..3902.767 rows=10 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=59875
   ->  Sort  (cost=410011.04..437703.22 rows=11076875 width=14) (actual time=3902.763..3902.763 rows=10 loops=1)
         Sort Key: userid
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
         Buffers: shared hit=59875
         ->  Seq Scan on users_act_demo  (cost=0.00..170643.75 rows=11076875 width=14) (actual time=0.028..1520.772 rows=11076719 loops=1)
               Buffers: shared hit=59875
Planning time: 0.145 ms
Execution time: 3902.827 ms
```

My question is, why isn't the sort faster ? If all of the data is not I/O bound, then isn't it CPU bound? Why is it slow and what exactly is the cost involved in here ?

Comment: For one thing, PostgreSQL can currently only use one CPU thread/core at a time. This will be improving in PostgreSQL 9.6. It's processing  and sorting 11 million rows in 3.9 seconds, which is not exactly lightning fast, but I wouldn't call it super slow when it's having to do it by brute force.

Comment: Yes, I completely agree that it is not slow, but I was thinking that CPU was not the bottleneck here and it was completely disk I/O, and yes PG is improving with each and every release, calling PG slow for a OLAP use case like this (without an index) is not fair :)